# How do I highlight paragraphs in a pdf using `react-pdf-viewer`

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to add text highlighting to an app that uses a PDF renderer (in this case `react-pdf-viewer`) but am having trouble in adding highlighting capabilities on a sentence / paragraph. My particular case is that it won't highlight a thing.

```
// import { Viewer, SpecialZoomLevel } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Worker, Viewer, SpecialZoomLevel } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";
// import { highlightPlugin } from "@react-pdf-viewer/highlight";
// Import styles
import "@react-pdf-viewer/highlight/lib/styles/index.css";
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";
// Import styles
import "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout/lib/styles/index.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { searchPlugin } from "@react-pdf-viewer/search";

const workerUrl = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.js`;

PDFView.propTypes = {
    pdfUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    highlightedText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default function PDFView({ pdfUrl, highlightedText }) {
    const searchPluginInstance = searchPlugin();
    const { highlight } = searchPluginInstance;

    const [documentLoad, onDocumentLoad] = useState(false);

    const handleDocumentLoad = () => {
        onDocumentLoad(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (documentLoad === true && highlightedText !== "") {
            console.log(highlightedText);
            // highlightPlugin.highlight(highlightedText);
            highlight(highlightedText);
            console.log("highlighted");
        }
    }, [documentLoad, highlightedText]);

    return (
        <div className="border-solid border-2 rounded-md border-slate-300 h-screen w-auto overflow-auto overscroll-contain">
            <Worker workerUrl={workerUrl}>
                <Viewer
                    fileUrl={pdfUrl}
                    defaultScale={SpecialZoomLevel.PageFit}
                    onDocumentLoad={handleDocumentLoad}
                    plugins={[searchPluginInstance]}
                />
            </Worker>
        </div>
    );
}
```

highlightedText here may refer to multiple paragraphs or sentences from a PDF that was scanned by using the unstructured library. How do I fix the error I'm running into? At first, I thought it may be an issue with using `unstructured` for PDF parsing, but when I tried hardcoding texts from the PDF file itself, it still won't highlight it.

I found `highlight()` works best on one word only and not a string of texts (sentences / paragraphs). I feel like I have to use [highlight plugin](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/plugins/highlight/) but the example code shown is for showing a new component after a text is highlighted and the documentation isn't clear on how to programmatically highlight a paragraph in a PDF file.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the keywords you want to highlight like this

```
const searchPluginInstance = searchPlugin({
     keyword: ['Hello', 'World']
})
```

Or like this if you want to exactly match the keywords

```
const searchPluginInstance = searchPlugin({
     keyword: [
       {
         keyword: 'Hello',
         matchCase: true
       }
     ]
})
```

You can also set the keywords in a state and pass it

```
const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState(['Hello', 'World'])
const searchPluginInstance = searchPlugin({
     keyword: keywords
})
```